# How to combine two NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have the following two `NSString`:

```
NSString *latitudeString, *longitudeString;

latitudeString = @"50.1338";
```

and

```
longitudeString = @"8.91583";
```

What I want to obtain is a NSString that looks like this: 50.1338,8.91583.

How do I obtain that?Thanks

IMPORTANT: The values I showed are only for the purpose of better understanding, ussually `latitudeString` and `longitudeString` have random values.

Comment: You'd like to put the two coordinates together as one string with a comma in the middle of each coord?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To get what you want you can use

```
NSString *coordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use stringWithFormat method

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
```

Answer (score 5):

A thousand years late:

```
[latitudeString stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@", longitudeString]
```

Would slightly reduce runtime parsing costs and, historically, would have given you greater type safety (before the compiler checked type strings). So some of us old timers got used to it and still mentally make the fairly feeble performance argument to justify what's comfortable.

```
[@[latitudeString, longitudeString] componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

May also be preferable if you'd rather raise an exception upon one string being missing than silently produce something nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
NSString *combine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it was better:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f,%.4f",[latitudeString floatValue],[longitudeString floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String* coord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
```

Answer (score 1):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",latitudeString,longitudeString];`